# Radius of convergence for $\sum a_kz^{2k}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

Let $R$ be radius of convergence of $\sum a_kz^k$ 
How do I find the radius of convergence for $\sum a_kz^{2k}$

My guess is $\sqrt{R}$ but I am not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obviously correct. Forget that $|a_n|^{1/n}$ thing. *By definition* the series $\sum a_kz^k$ converges when $|z|<R$ and diverges when $|z|>R$, hence $\sum a_kz^{2k}$ converges when $|z^2|< R$ and diverges when $|z^2|> R$.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct.

If $|z|<\sqrt R$, then $|z^2|=|z|^2<R$ and therefore the series$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_nz^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n(z^2)^k\tag1$$converges. And if $|z|>\sqrt R$, the series $(1)$ diverges, for a similar reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_{k} z^{k}$ is $R$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right|
$$
Also, the series $\sum a_{k}z^{2k}$ to be convergent, we need the limit
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}z^{2(k+1)}}{a_{k}z^{2k}}\right|=\frac{|z|^2}{R}
$$
to be less than $1$. Hence, the series $\sum a_{k}z^{2k}$ converges provided $\frac{|z|^2}{R}<1$, that is $|z|< \sqrt{R}$. The radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_{k}z^{2k}$ is therefore $\sqrt{R}$.